# How use XML-RPC in odoo 9 version

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-9

I need simple example (module) how use odoo XML-RPC.

Does anyone have an example except on odoo web documentation.

Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the example for xml RPC, hope it will help you.

```py
import xmlrpclib

username = 'admin' #the user
pwd = 'admin'      #the password of the user
dbname = 'test'    #the database

# odoo Common login Service proxy object 
sock_common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy ('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/common')
uid = sock_common.login(dbname, username, pwd)

#replace localhost with the address of the server
# odoo Object manipulation service 
sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object')

partner = {
   'name': 'Fabien Pinckaers',
   'lang': 'fr_FR',
}
#calling remote ORM create method to create a record 
partner_id = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'create', partner)
```

Comment: Tnx for help, I have two question where put above code .py or other extensions and how  call remote ORM create method.

Comment: Yes you need to put above code in  .py , but it is highly depends on which programming language you use to call xml rpc.